# Why does Nginx give a 502 error only for mobile devices?

Tags: mobile, nginx, configuration, ipv6

Using Nginx, I'm getting the error:

`Error 502 - Bad Request
The server could not resolve your request for uri: http://domain.name/file/path`

Oddly, I only get this error when my phone is using data from my cell carrier.  The server serves everything just fine when I am using my phone on Wi-Fi or when I'm using a desktop computer.  It even works when I am using my iPad conneted to my phone via Wi-Fi with my phone acting as a mobile hotspot.

The 502 error code suggests that there's an issue with reverse proxying or serving requests with php-fpm.  I'm doing neither of these.

Because this error is happening only under specific circumstances, I'm thinking it has to be something with the request my phone is sending. (Nexus 5, Chrome, Android Lollipop)

My nginx.conf and other configuration files are passing tests.  I used:

`sudo nginx -t`

and it said "the configuration file syntax is okay" and "configuration file test is successful."

What could be going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After tripple-checking my Nginx configuration, I had the idea to look at all tcp activity on port 80 of my server.

I installed tcpdump:

`sudo apt-get install tcpdump`

Then ran it, looking only for port 80 tcp traffic:

`sudo tcpdump 'tcp port 80' -i eth0`

I noticed that all other traffic was just 'IP', but when I sent a request from my phone, it was 'IP6'.

My server wasn't ipv6 enabled, but that's an easy fix with an additional listen directive:

`listen [::]:80;`

Comment: I just had the same issue, which took me forever to solve. If only I had googled the right thing to land here, or thought to use `tcpdump`! Ha.